# Exception in Character input java

Tags: java, input, try-catch, character

so i'm trying to take a character input in java 
and need to catch it using a try and catch statement if user inputs more than one character

```
choice=scnr.next().charAt(0);
```

any ideas of how should i use try-catch statement to do this ?

Comment: Theoretically `charAt()` may throw a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`, namely if the string is empty. Not sure whether it can happen in practice in your code, though.

Comment: The requirement to use `try`-`catch` sounds funny. A school assignment?

Comment: yep a school assignment ;-;

Answer (score 1):

No. You need not to try or catch here cause you won't run into any exception. You are just taking the first character of the input. That automatically ignores the next letters.

If you still want to warn user about entering string you can throw an exception manually

```
        String input = s.next();
        if (input.length() > 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please enter single character.");
        }
        char choice = input.charAt(0);
```

Comment: thanks but i need to take a input in try and catch statement
should i use something else to take an input which can throw an exception ?

Comment: Even if you take input inside try catch, you dont get an exception.

Comment: You can find ways of taking input that may theoretically throw `IOException` or can be controlled to throw `FileNotFoundException` (a subclass of `IOException`). I cannot think of a way that will by itself throw an exception if the user enters two characters instead of one. You may wrap the code from the answer in try/catch and catch the `IllegalArgumentException` throw, of course.